# How can I make a reserved word loose its special formatting in listings?

Tags: listings

Consider the following example.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=sh]
cat foo.c cat.c bar.c
echo The cat ate the cheese
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This formats the reserved words (cat in this case) in bold even in places where they should not be. Is there a way to avoid this with some markup in the code text? [image]

I could place these non-special words in quotes, which for Unix shell scripts would retain their functionality , but in many cases this defies common coding conventions.  Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps escaping to LaTeX could be an option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=sh,escapechar=@]
cat foo.c cat.c bar.c
echo The @cat@ ate the cheese
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```